# Does this proof by induction of the generalized triangle inequality rely too heavily on the inductive step?

Tags: functional-analysis

I've written a proof using induction for the generalized triangle inequality but I am worried the proof is circular and was hoping someone could let me know whether the proof holds.

The proof goes as follows:

We aim to prove that:

\begin{equation}
    d(x_{1}, x_{n}) \leq d(x_{1}, x_{2}) +...+d(x_{n-1}, x_{n}) \qquad (1)
\end{equation}

**Proof:**

We prove by induction on $k$.

For the base case, since $d$ defines a metric it is true by the fourth metric space axiom that

\begin{equation} 
    d(x_{1}, x_{3}) \leq d(x_{1}, x_{2}) + d(x_{2}, x_{3}) \qquad (2)
\end{equation}

Assume that the proposition is true for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ i.e.

\begin{equation}
    d(x_{1}, x_{k}) \leq d(x_{1}, x_{2}) +...+d(x_{k-1}, x_{k}) \qquad (3)
\end{equation}

We now prove for the $k+1$ term i.e.

\begin{equation}
    d(x_{1}, x_{k+1}) \leq d(x_{1}, x_{2}) +...+d(x_{k-1}, x_{k})+d(x_{k}, x_{k+1}) \qquad (4)
\end{equation}

Adding $d(x_{k}, x_{k+1})$ to both sides of (3) gives

\begin{equation}
    d(x_{1}, x_{k}) + d(x_{k}, x_{k+1}) \leq d(x_{1}, x_{2}) +...+d(x_{k-1}, x_{k})+d(x_{k},x_{k+1}) \qquad (5)
\end{equation}

Now note that by (2) (i.e. the triangle inequality)

\begin{equation}
    d(x_{1}, x_{k}) \leq d(x_{1}, x_{k-1}) + d(x_{k-1}, x_{k}) \qquad (6)
\end{equation}

Using this fact we note that

\begin{equation}
    d(x_{1}, x_{k+1}) \leq d(x_{1}, x_{k}) + d(x_{k}, x_{k+1}) \qquad (7)
\end{equation}

Plugging this into (5) gives

\begin{equation}
      d(x_{1}, x_{k+1}) \leq d(x_{1}, x_{k}) + d(x_{k}, x_{k+1}) \leq d(x_{1}, x_{2}) +...+d(x_{k-1}, x_{k})+d(x_{k}, x_{k+1})\qquad (8)
\end{equation}

and so

\begin{equation}
    d(x_{1}, x_{k+1}) \leq d(x_{1}, x_{2}) +...+d(x_{k-1}, x_{k})+d(x_{k}, x_{k+1}) \qquad (9)
\end{equation}

Since this is true for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ the proof is complete.

My worry is that this proof relies too heavily on the assumed proposition $d(x_{1}, x_{k}) \leq d(x_{1}, x_{2}) +...+d(x_{k-1}, x_{k})$. I know this is a common/ necessary part of induction proofs but I worry that there may not be good enough reasons to accept the proposition in this case.

My second question is: is it right to perform induction on $k$ or is it considered more clear to do it on $n$ since $n$ is used in the original inequality?

Comment: You keep switching between $k$ and $n$. It doesn't matter which letter you use, If I really wanted to I could use the letter $\xi$ everywhere as well. BUT, you should make a choice once and for all, and stick with it throughout. Also, your equations aren't numbered.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Yes, this was an oversite. The numbering is due having copied the latex from a seperate document. Should now be corrected.

Comment: I wouldn't bother writing (6) on the way to (7), since neither one is exactly the same as (2), so (6) isn't adding anything helpful. Other than this, this is a perfectly fine proof; I could see a more streamlined version of it, but that's just a matter of personal style and intended audience.

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks for the feedback. I'll correct the proof as you suggested. One of the things I'm trying to work on is streamlining. I find I always tend to do far too much and my proofs end up being kind of bloated as result. I think it's a result of wanting to be absolutly sure of things in my head. Something to work on, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Your way of doing the induction step is a bit confusing to me, so I try to write down a clean version. Hope this helps.

Assume (inductive hypothesis) that for every choice $x_1, \dotsc, x_n$ we have
$$ d(x_1, x_n) \leq d(x_1, x_2) + \dotsc + d(x_{n-1},x_n). $$

Take any $n+1$ points $x_1, \dotsc, x_{n+1}$. Then
$$ d(x_1, x_{n+1}) \leq d(x_1, x_n) + d(x_n,x_{n+1}) \leq d(x_1, x_2) + \dotsc + d(x_{n-1},x_n) + d(x_n,x_{n+1}), $$
as wanted. In the first inequality  we used the normal triangular inequality (base step), in the second we used the inductive hypothesis.

Comment: Ah ok this is actually a nicer way of introducing the inductive hypothesis. My wording is what I use normally and it's esentially just taken from the wording in standard intorductory proof courses I've seen. Many thanks for your input!